# Red Hat Fuse Quickstart app "Content Based Router - Java DSL" does not create "work" folder

Tags: java-8, apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, jboss-tools

### Problem

Red Hat Fuse Quickstart app "***Content Based Router - Java DSL***" template does not work. i.e., when built, run and deployed (to "Red Hat Fuse 7.1") the "work" folder is never created.

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.mycompany.camel;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file:work/cbr/input")  //<== "work" folder not created...
            .log("Receiving order ${file:name}")
            .choice()
                .when().xpath("//order/customer/country[text() = 'UK']")
                    .log("Sending order ${file:name} to the UK")
                    .to("file:work/cbr/output/uk")
                .when().xpath("//order/customer/country[text() = 'US']")
                    .log("Sending order ${file:name} to the US")
                    .to("file:work/cbr/output/us")
                .otherwise()
                    .log("Sending order ${file:name} to another country")
                    .to("file:work/cbr/output/others")
            .log("Done processing ${file:name}");
    }

}
```

Note that the "*Content Based Router - Blueprint DSL*"  **does** work (i.e., it uses blueprint.xml file to define route, rather than Java code).

I'm using the "quickstart" template found in "Red Hat Developer Studio".

i.e. File-->New-->Fuse Integration Project-->[create project name]-->choose "Standalone" platform,  choose "Karaf/Fuse on Karaf"--> under "Beginner" choose "Content Based Router - Java DSL" --> Finish-->  etc.

Built and hot deployed. The Java DSL quickstart project starts and runs - but, it stops short of creating the parent "work" folder (much less the other subfolders).

What might be missing from the template project and/or configuration?

I am wondering:  Is Java DSL going by the wayside in favor of Spring DSL and/or Blueprint DSL? (I had used Java DSL with old Jboss Fuse 6.3 and liked it).

For what it is worth, here is the the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-java-cbr</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Fuse CBR Quickstart - Java</name>
  <description>Camel Content-Based Router Example using the Java DSL</description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <properties>
    <version.maven-bundle-plugin>3.2.0</version.maven-bundle-plugin>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <jboss.fuse.bom.version>7.1.0.fuse-710023-redhat-00001</jboss.fuse.bom.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.fuse</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-fuse-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss.fuse.bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat EA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>jboss-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat JBoss Early Access Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
      <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ga-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat GA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>red-hat-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat EA Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>jboss-ea-repository</id>
      <name>Red Hat JBoss Early Access Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>myJavaDsl</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>Camel Content-Based Router Example using the Java DSL [myJavaDsl]</Bundle-Name></instructions></configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.mycompany.camel.Launcher</mainClass>
          <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

Red Hat Developer Studio, Version: 12.9.0.GA

fuse-karaf-7.1.0.fuse-710023-redhat-00001

jdk1.8.0_121

C:\apache-maven-3.6.0

[Using Quickstart projects are referred to in Red Hat Fuse Tooling User Guide - PDF](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.1/html/tooling_user_guide/ridernewproject)

Comment: What happens if you instead specify `file://C:/AAAInput` and `file://C:/BBBOutput` for the file endpoints?

Comment: hi T.  -No difference.  Folder is still not created.  thx! sd

Comment: "Built and hot deployed... The Java DSL quickstart project starts and runs - but, it stops short of creating the parent "work" folder (much less the other subfolders)...."

Which method are you using to build and deploy?
I tried and it is working fine if i right-click on project and launch as java application. Then right-click-> refresh on the project, the work/cbr/input folder is available.
When you say it "stops", do you have some specific logs?

Comment: @AurélienPupier yes, it is working as local Java application, but if I try to deploy it on Fuse runtime, the route is not started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following steps to make it work with Fuse runtime:

1. create a new Fuse Integration Project - Standalone, Karaf / Fuse on Karaf, CBR - Java DSL
2. create a new folders and file "src/main/resources/**OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml**
3. blueprint.xml file content:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="              http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd              http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <bean class="com.mycompany.camel.CamelRoute" id="myRouteBuilder"/>
    <camelContext id="cbr-example-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <routeBuilder ref="myRouteBuilder"/>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>`

4. deploy the project via *Servers* view in Red Hat Developer Studio

Because the file is in the OSGI-INF/blueprint directory inside our JAR, it will be automatically activated as soon as the bundle is installed. This is possible because Red Hat Fuse uses Apache Karaf with Blueprint deployer - see [Deploying into Apache Karaf - OSGi Services](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.2/html-single/deploying_into_apache_karaf/?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=70160000000dJVaAAM#DeploySimple)

Anyway, provided templates should work out-of-the-box. Therefore I raised an issue for the developers of Fuse Tooling - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-3178

Comment: Thank you, Tomas.

Comment: Ha!  checking back in today...  still not fixed.  (still have to add the OSGI-INF/blueprint/bluepring.xml).  Oh well...  :D

Comment: Yes, you're right. The dependent JIRA issue is still open - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-3178 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder permissions for C:\ and also use the uri as mentioned below:

from("file://C:/AAAInput/?autoCreate=true&noop=true")

Comment: Hi V.  - Tried this before, but - in the event I missed some syntactical nuance - I retried.   Folder still does not get created.  Thx!  sd

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your route didn't start at all. Try to use direct ref to route builder instead of package scan like this:

```
<camel:camelContext id="aaa.bbb.ccc.jar" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <camel:routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder"/>
</camel:camelContext>
<bean id="routeBuilder" class="aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.CamelRoute" />
```

Comment: thx, c0ld.  Unfortunately, made no difference.   wondering whether the quickstart template provided contains correct dependencies, etc for the standalone Java DSL routebuilder.